# Excel VBA if/elseif function with multiple conditions and dropdowns

Tags: string, vba, excel, function

I'm new to VBA and currently using it to create a function that uses three criteria to spit out a calculated result. The three input cells include one numeric value ("emissionsquantity") and two text values ("gas" and "units", both of which have values that are selected from drop-down menus.

I basically want to create a function that calculates a result based on the values selected from the drop-down menus. For example, if drop-down B ("gas") lists a certain value and drop-down C "units" lists a certain type of unit measurement, I want to use the quantity in column A to calculate a final value. Here is what I've started to develop so far (for one of the three pollutant types):

```
Function CO2EquivalentEmissions(emissionsquantity As Double, gas As String, units As String)
    If (gas = "CH4" Or "ch4") And units = "tons" Then
        CO2EquivalentEmissions = emissionsquantity * 25
    ElseIf (gas = "CH4" Or "ch4") And units = "lbs" Then
        CO2EquivalentEmissions = (emissionsquantity / 2000) * 25
    ElseIf (gas = "CH4" Or "ch4") And units = "tonnes" Then
        CO2EquivalentEmissions = (emissionsquantity * 1.10231) * 25
End If
End Function
```

Using this function, however, I get a result of 0.00, regardless of which value I use for "emissionsquantity". Any advice? Thanks so much!

Comment: try the code in my answer below

Answer (score 2):

You confused how to test the string a little, you misplaced the position of `"`, see code below:

```
Function CO2EquivalentEmissions(emissionsquantity As Double, gas As String, units As String)

If gas = "CH4" And units = "tons" Then
    CO2EquivalentEmissions = emissionsquantity * 25
ElseIf gas = "CH4" And units = "lbs" Then
    CO2EquivalentEmissions = (emissionsquantity / 2000) * 25
ElseIf gas = "CH4" And units = "tonnes" Then
    CO2EquivalentEmissions = (emissionsquantity * 1.10231) * 25
End If

End Function
```

**Edit 1**: with updated corrected `Function` (includes `Or` for **gas** criteria)

```
Function CO2EquivalentEmissions(emissionsquantity As Double, gas As String, units As String)

If (gas = "CH4" Or gas = "ch4") And units = "tons" Then
    CO2EquivalentEmissions = emissionsquantity * 25
ElseIf (gas = "CH4" Or gas = "ch4") And units = "lbs" Then
    CO2EquivalentEmissions = (emissionsquantity / 2000) * 25
ElseIf (gas = "CH4" Or gas = "ch4") And units = "tonnes" Then
    CO2EquivalentEmissions = (emissionsquantity * 1.10231) * 25
End If

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks, Shai. Yeah, that was an oversight on my part. I tweaked my code a bit and also added parentheses to allow for both lower-case and capital spelling of CH4, but I'm now getting the #VALUE! error in Excel. Any ideas? I posted the revised code above.

Comment: @user6851629 your syntax of using the `Or` is not correct. See my edited code

Answer (score 1):

There was a small mistake within the OR condition. Either do this:

```
Function CO2EquivalentEmissions(emissionsquantity As Double, gas As String, units As String)
If (gas = "CH4" Or gas = "ch4") And units = "tons" Then
    CO2EquivalentEmissions = emissionsquantity * 25
ElseIf (gas = "CH4" Or gas = "ch4") And units = "lbs" Then
    CO2EquivalentEmissions = (emissionsquantity / 2000) * 25
ElseIf (gas = "CH4" Or gas = "ch4") And units = "tonnes" Then
    CO2EquivalentEmissions = (emissionsquantity * 1.10231) * 25
End If
End Function
```

Or include option compare text, this will make all "text comparisons" case insensitive so you can simply have single check and that will work for CH4, cH4 etc.:

```
Option Compare Text
Function CO2EquivalentEmissions(emissionsquantity As Double, gas As String, units As String)

If (gas = "ch4") And units = "tons" Then
    CO2EquivalentEmissions = emissionsquantity * 25
ElseIf (gas = "ch4") And units = "lbs" Then
    CO2EquivalentEmissions = (emissionsquantity / 2000) * 25
ElseIf (gas = "ch4") And units = "tonnes" Then
    CO2EquivalentEmissions = (emissionsquantity * 1.10231) * 25
```

End If
End Function